# Every topological space $X$ has the initial topology with respect to the family of continuous functions from $X$ to the Sierpiński space.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I am currently reading about initial topologies w.r.t. the Sierpiński space, and on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology) I read the following

> Every topological space $X$ has the initial topology with respect to the family of continuous functions from $X$ to the Sierpiński space.

Could someone explain to me what that means, is it that every topology could be represented as an initial topology w.r.t. to Sierpiński space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every space you can do the following. Take any space $Y$ and let $\mathcal F$ be the family of all continuous maps from $X$ to $Y$. Now equip $X$ with the initial topology with respect to this family. It is the coarsest topology making all $f\in\mathcal F$ continuous and has as subbase the preimages $f^{-1}(U)$ of open sets $U$ in $Y$ under these $f$'s. Clearly, this topology will always be coarser than the topology you started with, since by construction the original topology made these maps continuous.

Now let $\mathcal F$ be the family of all continuous functions from $X$ to the Siepiński space $S=\{a,b\}$, where $\{a\}$ is the only non-trivial open set. Then the statement says that the initial topology w.r.t. $\mathcal F$ will not be strictly coarser than the $\tau$. To show this, all you have to do is to take an open set $U$ and find a continuous map $f:X\to S$, such that $U=f^{-1}(\{a\})$.

One can try other spaces for $Y$. For instance, take $Y=\Bbb R$ or $Y=[0,1]$. Then you get the spaces with a well-known property. Can you find out which it is?

Comment: Thanks for you answer! But regarding your last paragraph, if I take $Y = \mathbb R$, then $\mathcal F$ is the set of all continuous functions from $X$ to $\mathbb R$, and when I consider the usual topology on $\mathbb R$ a basis for the initial-topology is given by $\{ f^{-1}((a,b)) \mid a,b \in \mathbb R \}$, but what else could be said about this topology, is there something more interesting to say?

Comment: @Stefan: Indeed there is. One can prove that a space with the initial topology of all continuous real-valued maps is completely regular. Conversely, if $X$ is completely regular, then the preimages $f^{-1}(U)$, $U\subset\Bbb R$, $f:X\to\Bbb R$ cont., for a base for the topology on $X$, so it also has the initial topology w.r.t. all cont. real-valued maps. (One can always replace $\Bbb R$ by the unit interval $I$ here.)

Answer (score 2):

Consider a topological space $X$ (let's call its topology $\mathcal{T}$). Let $S$ be the Sierpiński space. Let
$$F=\{\text{continuous functions }f\colon X\to S\}.$$
Let $\mathcal{T}'$ be the initial topology on $X$ for the family of functions $F$ -  that is, the smallest topology on $X$ under which every function in $F$ is continuous (this is the intersection of all topologies on $X$ that have this property). Then the statement is saying that in fact $\mathcal{T}=\mathcal{T}'$.

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ is a topological space, and $S$ is the Sierpinski Space, then the set of continuous functions $f:X\to S$ is in $1-1$ correspondence with the open sets of $X$. So the topology is entirely determined by the set of continuous functions from $X$ to $S$.

Let $S=\{0,1\}$ be the space with open sets $\emptyset,\{0\},\{0,1\}$. Then for $U\subseteq X$ open, we define $f_U:X\to S$ by $f_U(x)=0$ if $x\in U$ and $f_U(x)=1$ if $x\not\in U$. This is continuous.

We can also see that if $f:X\to S$ is continuous, then $f=f_U$ where $U=f^{-1}(\{0\})$.